# String matching

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, strings, string-matching

I need to design a data structure to which I can efficiently add new words(Strings) and search for an existing word. Also, the search word can contain `.` in it which can match any character. For eg. if I add strings "abcd" and "abed" then search for "ab.d" should return me both of them.

I tried to tackle this using prefix Tries. It works fine for normal string search(without dot) but for dot I have to search for every child of a node. Is there a more efficient way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was considered in the following papers:

- [Partial-match retrieval algorithms](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/Riv76b.pdf).  Ronald L. Rivest.  SIAM Journal of Computing, volume 5, number 1, March 1976.
- [Fast Text Searching for Regular Expressions or Automaton Searching on Tries](http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~mfc/cs120/papers/ptrees.pdf).  Ricardo A. Baeza-Yates, Gaston H. Gonnet.  Journal of the ACM, volume 43, number 6, 1996.

See also [String matching for wildcard-based records](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/49148/755), [Given a set of string patterns, find which ones match a particular string](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/65505/755), https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/36913/5038.