# How to implement a faceted search efficiently

Tags: search-algorithms

I know Solr and the likes are able to provide faceted search out-of-the-box. But how is faceted search actually implemented technically?

How are those engines able to efficiently search for items based on a dynamic list of attributes given by a query and to provide pagination at the same time?

Definition : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search .. even Wikipedia does not list down the technical details

Comment: This link contains a few nuggets of info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847909/efficient-implementation-of-faceted-search-in-relational-databases

Comment: What's faceted search?  Can you edit your question to provide a self-contained definition?

Comment: @D.W. multidimensional search, like what Solr does..

Comment: Can you edit the question to give a self-contained definition of faceted search?  I'm not sure what multidimensional search is, either, and I'm not familiar with Solr.  It would also be great to summarize what you've found so far in the question, to help others with a similar question (e.g., from that Stack Overflow question, if it turns out to be relevant).

Comment: @D.W. see my edit

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/95665/755

Comment: @D.W. how is faceted search related to string matching